# Need help - embed Google My Business Posts into website

Tags: google-api, google-my-business-api

I'm looking for an api or another way to grab posts (not reviews) from google my business and embed them to a website.  We don't want to have to place the updates/posts at two different places...google my business and the actual website.

I'm already grabbing reviews using the google places API but didn't find any solutions for actual posts

appreciate any directions to the end result...thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business)

The method to fetch Google My Business posts is [accounts.locations.localPosts.list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts/list)

Comment: [Links are not answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/).